# C++ inheritance private members

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I have a question about inheritance:

For example I have a base class A with private members: x, y

I have getter functions getx and gety,
I want to use the getter functions from A to class B that inherits from A,

But my problem is that x and y are private members of A
I cant access the private of A from B.

So I need to create two x,y for class B but that way I wont be able to use the get functions of class A.

Any help? I dont know how I can access the private members of A without creating new ones. Maybe with the constructor? But I am not sure how.

Comment: Private members cannot be accessed from derived classes. Use protected members instead. Think of them as private, except for inheritance, whereas public members are accessible for every class.

Comment: better show code instead of describing code in english. Details do matter, and to point you in the right direction it would be good to see what exactly is `A` and `B`

Comment: why do you want to access private members of a different class? They are not meant to be accessed from outside, thats why they are private

Comment: so what can I do about my functions? beacuse if I cant use the get functions of A and  I will have to create new functions in B so i wont need the inheirtance

Comment: if the functions are public you can call them, but please post a [mcve]

Comment: @shahar don't use `private` but `protected` instead. Protected class members can be accessed from within inherited classes.

Comment: ... and do what you've already been told: [edit] your question and show the relevant parts of your code. Don't describe your code but show it.

Answer (score 1):

Private members are always private. They can't be accessed from outside classes at any cost. You can try `protected` instead, consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

// Base class
class A {
    protected: // declaration for protected vars which are clearly accessible to B
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        void setX(int w) { x = w; }
        void setY(int h) { y = h; }
};

// Derived class
class B: public A { // derives A
    public:
    int multiply() { 
        return (x * y); // accesses x and y from class A
    }
};
```

The `x` and `y` are accessed from Class A to derived Class B.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

C++ provides the Protected mechanism which you might want to use. Take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).

You could make members x and y of Class A protected so that Class B which inherits from A can access them.

```
class A{
protected:
int x;
int y;
};

class B : public A{

public:
 void somefn(int someval){
   x = someval; //A::x is being set here.
}
};
```